# Angular2 routing: (why) do I _need_ to specify LocationStrategy?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I've been having a hard time getting routing to work in Angular2. Then I tried John Papas "Angular2-go" starter, and routing worked straight away. After some comparing/diffing, it turns out the only thing I was missing was the "provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})" during bootstrap!

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})]);
```

Do we always need to specify this? What options are there? I found numerous examples that *didn't* include this, are they just outdated or am I missing something? I found nothing in the docs so far...

Answer (score 0):

See [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4735). At this moment the default location strategy is [`PathLocationStrategy`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.45/modules/angular2/src/router/path_location_strategy.ts) (see [source codes here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.45/modules/angular2/router.ts#L113)), which requires some server tuning from you. But it looks like the situation can be changed in the future.

Comment: Thanks! So the default is opposite to ng1, I guess. I wasn't aware (and the console.error didn't help a lot either).